# facebook event start date format + iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am using FBGraph api to fetch events from Facebook. I am getting proper response. But, I am not getting proper dateformat for start_time and end_time.

Right now I am getting this kind of format 2013-01-23T19:50:00+0530.
I want to convert it in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" formatter.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss+SSSS"];

try this formatter .. its working ..